# Extend a job's dependsOn in a template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm creating a template in which I pass a job list. In this template, I add a "pre" job to the job list, and then add all jobs. I'd like to be able to add a dependency on the "pre" job to all jobs in the job list, without breaking any dependencies between the jobs in the joblist parameter. My template looks something like this:

```
parameters:
  - name: Jobs
    type: jobList

jobs:
- job: prejob
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "This is my prejob"
- ${{ each job in parameters.Jobs }}:
  - ${{ each pair in job }}:
      ${{ if and(ne(pair.key, 'steps'),ne(pair.key, 'dependsOn')) }}:
        ${{ pair.key }}: ${{ pair.value }}
    dependsOn: 'prejob'
    steps:
    - ${{ job.steps }}
```

now this of course overwrites the dependsOn of the jobs passed.

What can I change in the template so I can join the passed job dependencies with the `prejob` job? The `join` expression joins 2 arrays, but my `prejob` text is not an array, and I'm not sure the `dependsOn` property of a job is always an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this:

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: Jobs
    type: jobList

jobs:
- job: prejob
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "This is my prejob"
- ${{ each job in parameters.Jobs }}:
  - ${{ each pair in job }}:
      ${{ if and(ne(pair.key, 'steps'),ne(pair.key, 'dependsOn')) }}:
        ${{ pair.key }}: ${{ pair.value }}
    dependsOn:
    - 'prejob'
    - ${{ if job.dependsOn }}:
      - ${{ job.dependsOn }}
    steps:
    - ${{ job.steps }}
```

In that way you should be able to make dependency to `prejob` and keep dependencies from jobs.

Comment: I'll give it a go, but are you sure that syntax is allowed for dependson? According to the documentation it should be in the array (square brackets) syntax (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#stage)

Comment: Yes. You have even example like this in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#template-expressions)

Comment: It appears you are right. The yaml docs are really inconsistent and information is scattered. All other information about dependson states you need to use the ['a','b'] syntax. If the "normal" y'all syntax is allowed I don't understand why it is not the default example. Thanks! I'll test it but I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work

Comment: @PaulVrugt Kindly let us know your test result.

Comment: I will, but I won't be able to test it until monday

Comment: @PaulVrugt That's fine. Looking forward to your update.

Comment: It works, too bad I didn't find this doc myself. Thanks!